# Are there existing random graph models that allow controlling assortativity?

Tags: graph-theory, expected-value, random-graphs

Here, we are talking about degree assortativity (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assortativity).
We know that the expected assortativity of graphs generated by Erdos-Renyi or Chung-Lu asymptotically approaches zero, and the Block Two-Level Erdos-Renyi (BTER) model generates graphs with highly positive assortativity.
Are there existing random graph models that allow controlling assortativity in both directions?

References:

1. Noldus, Rogier, and Piet Van Mieghem. "Assortativity in complex networks." Journal of Complex Networks 3.4 (2015): 507-542.
2. Seshadhri, Comandur, Tamara G. Kolda, and Ali Pinar. "Community structure and scale-free collections of Erdős-Rényi graphs." Physical Review E 85.5 (2012): 056109.

---

#### 2023-11-10

In Newman's original paper on assortativity, a sampling-based edge-rewiring mechanism is proposed for controlling assortativity.
Also, Newman and Park proposed a model with controllable assortativity, but limited to non-negative assortativity.

Reference:

1. Newman, Mark EJ. "Assortative mixing in networks." Physical review letters 89.20 (2002): 208701.
2. Newman, Mark EJ, and Juyong Park. "Why social networks are different from other types of networks." Physical review E 68.3 (2003): 036122.

Comment: Well, Newman's original paper on assortativity proposed a method for generating graphs with a given assortativity, though it's hard to imagine studying it analytically - it's a Metropolis-Hastings kind of thing.

Comment: @MishaLavrov Thanks! In fact, in <Newman, Mark EJ, and Juyong Park. "Why social networks are different from other types of networks." Physical review E 68.3 (2003): 036122>, they proposed a model with controllable assortativity, but only non-negative assortativity is possible